# Travel time from Terminal A to Terminal C of Ezeiza (Ministro Pistarini International Airport, Buenos Aires)

Tags: airports, argentina, buenos-aires, eze

How long does it take to go from Terminal A to Terminal C of Ministro Pistarini Airport  (EZE, Buenos Aires)?

Answer (score 2):

Terminals A and C ("Mercedes Sosa") at Ezeiza (Ministro Pistarini International Airport) are separated by Terminal B, which is about 376 metres long. On foot that distance should take a few minutes. Wayde van Niekerk has run further in 43.03 seconds.

Diagram (no scale) courtesy [iFly.com](http://www.ifly.com/ezeiza-international-airport/terminal-map):

[image: Ezeiza]